# How to let Android accessibility talkback pronounce TextInputLayout error

Tags: android, accessibility, android-textinputlayout, talkback

I have a `TextInputLayout` with a custom EditText like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/complaint_user_email_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"
    android:contentDescription="@string/complaint_user_email"
    android:labelFor="@+id/required_complaint_user_email">

    <com.company.app.ui.customview.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/required_complaint_user_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/complaint_user_email"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLength="100"
        app:field_is_required="true" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Most accessibility of the edittext is working, so the hint/label is pronounced  by the talkback. The problem however, is when I set a validation error for the field programatically in the code:

```
    complaint_user_email_layout.isErrorEnabled = true
    complaint_user_email_layout.error = getString(stringId)
```

The error below the EditText isn't seen by the talkback function and it won't pronounce it when I select the field. How do I accomplice such behaviour?

Answer (score -2):

This behaviour comes out-of-the-box with the new material component: `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`.

No configuration needed, and also works with a custom EditText.

https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Using `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`, I can say that it does NOT work in a way that the OP has described they need. Also, it seems that the link you have provided offers no information pertinent to this question.